# How to read OpenGL color buffer and depth buffer quickly?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glreadpixels

I have to read color buffer and depth buffer every frame. I know the `glReadPixels` function is very slow, so I would like to know if there is a faster way to do the reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `glReadPixels` isn't fast enough, you have a couple of options:

1) Whatever post processing you need to do, do on the GPU via [glsl](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/), [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/), [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html), or some other [GPGPU](http://gpgpu.org) solution

2) Do an [asynchronous PBO read back](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) on one thread while you start processing the next frame on another thread

3) Optimize other stuff so that a slow read back doesn't hurt performance elsewhere